# Search for ID in another table from a list of duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to get a list from the table Orders where the Column Email_Id from the table Users contain duplicates (rows in Users with duplicated emails).

```
SELECT
    o.[Email], o.[Email_Id], d.intCount
FROM (
     SELECT [Email], COUNT(*) as intCount
     FROM [Server].[dbo].[Table]
     GROUP BY [Email]
     HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) AS d
    INNER JOIN [Server].[dbo].[Table] o ON o.[Email] = d.[Email]
```

So I did try with the following:

```
SELECT * FROM [Server].[dbo].[Orders]
WHERE [Email_Id] IN/
    SELECT
        o.[Email], o.[Email_Id], d.intCount
    FROM (
         SELECT [Email], COUNT(*) as intCount
         FROM [Server].[dbo].[Users]
         GROUP BY [Email]
         HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ) AS d
        INNER JOIN [Server].[dbo].[Users] o ON o.[Email] = d.[Email]
)
```

Which returns a **Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.**

Also tried with:

```
SELECT [Order_Is], (
SELECT
        o.[Email], o.[Email_Id], d.intCount
    FROM (
         SELECT [Email], COUNT(*) as intCount
         FROM [Server].[dbo].[Users]
         GROUP BY [Email]
         HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ) AS d
        INNER JOIN [Server].[dbo].[Users] o ON o.[Email] = d.[Email]
    )
as [Email_Id]
FROM [Server].[dbo].[Orders]
```

With same results.

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Added `sql-server` tag based on the syntax used

Comment: The second try looks promising, only the `IN` keyword require the same column to compare with, no multiple columns.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Server].[dbo].[Orders]
JOIN ( SELECT [Email], [Email_Id], 
               count(*) over (partition by [Email]) as cnt
         FROM [Server].[dbo].[Users] ) tt
  on tt.[Email_Id] = [Orders].[Email_Id] 
 and tt.[cnt] > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

in your `WHERE` statement subquery, you can only have one field or expression for `IN` operator, that's what the error says, try this way:

```
SELECT * FROM [Server].[dbo].[Orders]
WHERE [Email_Id] IN (
    SELECT
        o.[Email_Id]
    FROM (
         SELECT [Email], COUNT(*) as intCount
         FROM [Server].[dbo].[Users]
         GROUP BY [Email]
         HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ) AS d
        INNER JOIN [Server].[dbo].[Users] o ON o.[Email] = d.[Email]
)
```